# FabricJs: IText adds extra padding

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I'm using FabricJs to create some text layers but I'm having problems with the alignment lines. The text layers are being created with and extra empty space between the layer boundaries and the actual text.
What I'm trying to achieve is that the alignment lines fit to the text limits, however, they are aligned including the empty space even if padding is set to 0 (which is the default value).

I have tried to come with a hacky solution, adding -7px padding on the layer, but still looks odd.

```
var iText2 = new fabric.IText('Text with negative padding', {
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    left: 100,
    top: 250,
    fill: "#000000",
    stroke: "",
    padding: -7,
    transparentCorners: true
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grieverll/5gabg92k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a hacky solution. I've modified the AligningGuidelines function from fabricJS so it works diferent for iText layers.

```
            if (activeObject.typeL == 'TEXT' && !activeTransformed) {
                activeObjectHeight -= (activeObjectHeight / 2.2);
                activeTransformed = true;
            }

            if (canvasObjects[i].typeL == 'TEXT') {
                objectHeight -= (objectHeight / 2.2);

            }

            if (canvasObjects[i].typeL !== 'TEXT' && activeObject.typeL !== 'TEXT') {
                //Default function code
            }
```

Basically, if the active object is aligned to another object or text layers, I force a modified height.